# I lost wight a lot but my waist size is exactly the same! Why?

Tags: bellyfat

I am (male - 28 years old) 171 cm. I was 68 kg (with waist 102 cm) two months ago and I am 63 kg now and still my waist 102 cm!! My food change was reducing fat intake and increasing vegetables and eating less than before. When fat burns it will burn from **everywhere**, but I didn't lose fat from my stomach. why??

Comment: Dieting without exercising = loss of muscle mass. Your body was programmed thousands years ago, when having energy reserves to survive was far more important that having a beach body. If you simply starve it without sending powerful signals that you need your muscles to survive, it will happily eat muscle and keep the fat. Yeap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a misconception here. Not all weight lost is fat. Some of it is definitely muscle. Probably at least half.

Yes, when you burn fat, you burn fat from everywhere, but the repositories in and around your stomach area are far larger than the others. Getting a noticable reduction in waist girth means you simply have to lose more fat.

But at the same time, I have to draw a question mark here. 68kgs at 171cm doesn't seem obese for a male. In fact, I'd wager that a good bit of the weight you lost was muscle mass. And if you didn't achieve a noticable change in waist size, this strengthens the theory that you didn't lose as much *fat* as you thought.